# How to convert specific columns values in pandas to list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

In the following `pandas Dataframe:`

```
alfa  alfa_id    beta    beta_id
ak   23          ji    24
bc   24          kl    25
```

I want to convert the columns `alfa and beta` to list.

```
cols = [l for l in df.columns.values if not l.endswith('id')]
df = df[cols].applymap(lambda c:[list(c)])
# gives me
```

**Output I am getting now:**

```
print(df)

alfa      beta    
[[a, k]]  [[j, i]]
```

** But, Expected output is:**

```
alfa      alfa_id    beta       beta_id
[[a, k]]   23        [[j, i]]    24
```

- **The columns for `alfa_id and beta_id` are lost but I want them back in one line code (as simple as possible).**
- I am looking for a method which also keeps the memory foot print low.

**PS note: I could have done**

```
df = df.applymap(lambda c:[list(c)] if type(c) is str else c)
```

But, I don't want this because there will be some other columns which should not be converted to list. So, I wanted to make `cols` values specifically which needs to be converted to list.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***setup***

```
cols = ['alfa', 'beta']
```

***new answer***

```
df.assign(**df[cols].stack().apply(list).unstack().to_dict('list'))

     alfa  alfa_id    beta  beta_id
0  [a, k]       23  [j, i]       24
1  [b, c]       24  [k, l]       25
```

***old answers***

***option 1***

```
df[cols].applymap(list)
```

***option 2***

```
df[cols].stack().apply(list).unstack()
```

***yield***

```
     alfa    beta
0  [a, k]  [j, i]
1  [b, c]  [k, l]
```

Comment: I think I confused you with the output I am expecting. Actually, I want the `alfa_id` and others_id back into the `dataframe` in a memory efficient way.